# MUI snackbar div persist on DOM after being closed

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I created a global modal with the purpose of only calling it when I need it, but the problem is that the **snackbar** div persists in the DOM and this causes certain elements to be blocked because they are below this div. Any idea what the problem would be?

My GlobalAlert component:

```
export function GlobalAlert() {
  const {alertState, handleClose} = useAlertContext();
  const {open, type, message} = alertState;

  function TransitionDown(props: TransitionProps) {
    return <Slide {...props} direction="down" />;
  }

  return (
    <Snackbar
      key={"top" + "center"}
      TransitionComponent={TransitionDown}
      anchorOrigin={{vertical: "top", horizontal: "center"}}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      disableWindowBlurListener={true}
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <Alert severity={type} sx={useStyles.alert} variant="filled" onClose={handleClose}>
        {message}
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
}
```

Context where I get the info

```
const AlertContextProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [alertState, setAlertState] = React.useState<AlertState>({
    open: false,
    type: "error",
    message: "",
  });

  const handleClose = React.useCallback((event?: React.SyntheticEvent | Event, reason?: string) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }
    setAlertState({
      open: false,
      type: "error",
      message: "",
    });
  }, []);

  const value = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      alertState,
      setAlertState,
      handleClose,
    }),
    [alertState, handleClose],
  );

  return <AlertContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
};
```

Bug image
[image: bug]

Comment: Maybe you could use the same open variable to decide if render or not by using a one line if statement like this:  {open ? <Snackbar /> : null}

Comment: As far as I remember when when Snackbar is closed, there shouldn't be DOM elements) left (but maybe I'm wrong). Can you share a reproducible link?

Answer (score 0):

I added the line below as `Snackbar` props to solve it.

```
ClickAwayListenerProps={{ onClickAway: () => null, }}
```

I'm using MUI 5.

Maybe [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#notistack) can help too.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue with snackbar. when snack bar has autoHideDuration value is set, it sets intermediate div block 'visibility: hidden' instead of none.
My workaround was to sett snackbar style div display to 'none' when snackbar is on close state using sx prop. here is my example.

```
<Snackbar
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
          open={snackbarOpen}
          autoHideDuration={3000}
          onClose={handleClose}
          message={message}
          TransitionComponent={TransitionLeft}
          //  action={action}
          ContentProps={{
                sx: {background : "green", }
            }}
          sx={{ display : () => snackbarOpen ? 'block' : 'none'} } 
            />
```

[sample code to set display none on close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZgHX.png)

Comment: Please share all code in text form, not hidden in a screenshot